# Cronjob on Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry stops right after execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, cron, cron-task

I use a RaspberryPi 3 with UbuntuMate 16.04. On it, I want to start a little Python (3.5) program every midnight. For that I call a little shell script, so that I can change into the wanted directory comfortably.

crontab:

```
5 0 * * * /path/to/script/start.sh
```

start.sh (yes, it's executable):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/wanted/workingDir/
python3.5 ControllerQueue.py
#also tried: python3.5 ControllerQueue.py &
```

Now if I execute the programm or script from the terminal, everything runs fine. But if I use the crontab it starts the script and stops right after. I also tried running the programm directly but get the same outcome. The paths are correct as I copied the workingDir path from the crontab-file and started it via the terminal.

Is there something I overlook?

Comment: I already had that added in my python script but thanks for the reference :)

Comment: Check the Environment  `PATH` running from `cron`, add this line to your `start.sh`: `set|grep PATH >> /tmp/start.sh.log`. Verify if `python3.5` is in your `PATH`.

Comment: Relevant: [how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)

Comment: You are right, python wasn't in the PATH my cronjobs were using. I added it but I still have the same problem. The python script starts for a second and dissapears again.

Comment: Add `>> /tmp/start.sh.log` to both lines in your `start.sh` and check the output. To catch error output do: [how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash)

Comment: Thank you very much. I got an error saying, that there is no display to connect to. I didn't think that I need to add support for that as the script doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stofvl suggested, I saved the error output of my shell script. It turns out that I needed to add a display. My programm is divided into two scripts. One which provides a GUI and the other main application. The script only starts the main application, without the GUI, but it seems that this didn't matter.

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518073/trying-to-run-a-python-script-from-ubuntu-crontab/26921337#26921337/) helped me solve the problem.